# How do I select an integer before a "+" sign in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm currently working on a calculator and for certain reasons (long story) I don't want to use the eval function.

so what I want to do is

```
var exp = document.form.textview.value; 
//everything on the calc is displayed in a form
var a = intiger up until the + sign
```

Now I have no idea how to do it, I tried doing

```
var a = exp.charAt(0)
```

but that just gives me the first character, what if the number is 2 digits.

all help is appreciated and thank you for reading
have a nice day,
larwa

Comment: could you please explain it?

Comment: not sure if I can follow your thoughts - I suggest using variables for state and this thing with + will represent your state - so there is no issue converting your output back - also check common patterns if something fits

Answer (score 1):

So as i understand it you're trying to find all characters up to the + sign
In the example of 12324+ you want to return 12324?

I would therefore use the "split" method on the string.

```js
var value = "12324+";
var number = value.split('+')[0];
```

This will split the string into an array and return the first index (the number) to the number variable

Comment: So your example would be: var a = exp.split('+')[0];

Comment: `value` should be string. `var value = "12324+";
`

Comment: thx, if I change the 0 to 1 , will it select the numbers after the +??

Comment: @FlyingRaptor Yes,

Answer (score 0):

#### Recognize an integer at the beginning of your input string:

JS' `parseInt` function does pretty much what you want, e.g. using your var names:

```
var a = parseInt(exp);
```

For a working example, see here:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#inp').keyup(function(ev){
    const val = $(ev.target).val();

    // this is the important part:
    const int = parseInt(val);

    console.log(int);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" />
<h3>value:</h3>
<div id="out">
</div>
```

#### Recognize all integers in your input string

To get all occurrences of integers in your input string you may use

```
var a = exp.match(/-?\d+/g).map(s => parseInt(s))
```

which will return an array of all separate integers. Working example:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#inp').keyup(function(ev){
    const val = $(ev.target).val();

    // this is the important part:
    const matches = val.match(/-?\d+/g).map(s => parseInt(s));

    console.log(matches);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" />
<h3>value:</h3>
<div id="out">
</div>
```

Comment: @customcommander True. Changed the RegExp to match an optional minus sign. Also mapped the matches from String to Integer.